# Sorting by part of a line in a list from a file

Tags: c++, sorting

This is for a C++ program. I'm not entirely sure how to formulate the problem I'm having. It's for a school assignment and I'm not looking for the answer just a point in the right direction. we need to read in a file with 75,000+ lines that look similar to this:

Census Tract 201, Autauga County, Alabama|9.84473419420788|1808|**183.651479494869**

Census Tract 202, Autauga County, Alabama|3.34583234555866|2355|**703.860730836106**

Census Tract 203, Autauga County, Alabama|5.35750339330735|3057|**570.60159846447**

wherein we need to sort by that last number in bold (using Quick and Merge sort from two different programs). I've got the sorting down to where if I only had to deal with the bold numbers I'd be set, but I'm having an issue getting the whole thing into a vector or array and being able to access specifically that part and sort by it. At the risk of making this way too long I'm not going to post the code I have so far. I'd just like a concept of how to attack this issue.

Comment: Does the whole file fit in memory?

Comment: read strings, look for the last `|` character, and parse out the final field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the following:
1. Create a class or structure with one member for each field.
2. Overload `operator>>` for your class.
3. Create a `std::vector` of your class.
4. Read the data file into your `std::vector` of class objects.

You can sort the `std::vector` by writing *functors* (function objects) that compare by a field, then passing that functor to the `std::sort` algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`regex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/). You basically need to match the content after the last `|`.

This pattern should work ([working example at regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3ga55)):

```
/\|([\d\.]+)$/gm
```

**Explanation**

- `\|` matches a literal `|`
- `(...)` creates a capture group (this is the group that you will want to extract)
- `[...]` creates a character set
- `\d` captures digits
- `\.` captures literal `.`s
- `+` tells the parser to grab 1 or more of the previous token (in this case, the character group)
- `$` matches the end of the line
- `g`, `m` match globally and multi-line, respectively

Thus the entire regex says match starting at a `|` and then group all digits and `.` in a capture group until the end of the line.